# check if user activated their account via email and display message after clicking on activation link PHP/JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

I'm working with the Zend Framework on a project that requires the user to activate their account by checking their email and clicking on the activation link. The activation link works fine and the user can login once their account is set active. My question is how can i display a message when the user clicks on the activation link and get redirected to the home page, acknowledging that their account has been activated.

I was trying to write an if statement to check if HTTP_REFERER = the URL of the activation link. But that didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the if statement:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'activationLinkGoesHere'){ ?>

    $("#suc_message").html('<?php echo 'Your account has been activated!';?>');
    $("#suc_message").fadeIn(2000);
    $("#suc_message").fadeOut(20000);

<?php } ?>

});
</script>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: thank you all for your input. You have no idea how much you just helped me. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the original answer, I did not read this properly.

I personally would just add something on the end of the url:

```
http://mysite.com/thanks.php?Reg=1
```

..and look for the reg part and inject the message if it exists.

**edit**

Returning to this, I'll add that it is very important to keep the url addition to something that is a boolean value. For example, you could display multiple messages if you found `?Reg=1` or `?LoggedIn=1` and displayed "You registered OK" and "You logged in OK" respectively.

Don't pass anything in that your javascript then *uses* for display or otherwise.

Don't make it fire any actions.

Follow the above and you'll be safe from people fiddling with the url to have fun with you.

Comment: Extra marks to me for not reading the question properly - *shamed*

Comment: this was the easiest way for me to make it work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you couldn't set a session variable on the activation page and then check for it in php on the home page?  If it's set, use php to inject some javascript (just a simple boolean flag should do) that you then check when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Zend Framework, then you must use [FlashMessenger](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html). It's designed for that exact purpose.

Remember to use the helper's static method in your controller's action.

Then for the view use [noumenal's](http://blog.noumenal.co.uk/2009/08/using-zend-framework-flashmessenger.html) excellent view helper; you can then put it in your layout or view script.

It's that easy. Hope it helps.